# WP Plugins won't coexist

Tags: wordpress

I am using these 2 plugins:

HTML Page Sitemap
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-sitemap/installation/

SyntaxHighlighter Evolved
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

When activating SyntaxHighlighter, HTML Page Sitemap won't render anymore (no output created).

Any idea as to why this may happen?

It's weird because I'd assume these aren't really playing in the same space...

Help is appreciated!

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress being a wide open playing ground for any number of programmers, beginners and experts alike, can lead to conflicts in a huge number of ways.

My best guess, without looking into the anatomy of each plugin you listed, would be that they are using some common element. Like, for example, a common function name or a common DOM element ID in output.

If the plugin is active, it can be called on every page load. It all depends on who wrote the plugin. You should crack them both open and do some inside investigation.